# How to read csv file and split them by comma

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, command-line

Here's the sample input

```
Pat,Stay,7,14
Sam,Pere,3,16
```

I want to substact like 14-7 and 16-3 and if the value is greater than 10 i want to print the name.

Output

```
sam
```

Comment: Check `awk` man page or tutorial

Comment: If you insist on using bash, you could use [cut](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) to parse the fields into variables, then subtract and process.  A higher-level alternative would be [awk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/index.htm).  But frankly, I'd encourage you to consider using a  scripting language like Perl or Python, or a compiled language like  C++ or Java.

Comment: ["Can I have an answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67856424/how-to-read-csv-file-and-split-them-by-comma#comment119937966_67856424) comes across as extremely rude and demanding. You might want to delete that comment and bear in mind in future that this is a forum where people try to help you for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming input.txt has these strings. You can use awk like this:

```
awk -F ',' '{if($4-$3 > 10) print $1}' input.txt
```

Comment: Awk scripts are made up of `condition { action }` statements so don't put the condition inside the action, leave it as the condition: `awk -F ',' '$4-$3 > 10{print $1}' input.txt`